# Sampling from a subset of data

Tags: r, subset, sub-array

I have the following problem.

I have multiple subarrays (say 2) that I have populated with character labels (1, 2, 3, 4, 5). My algorithm selects labels at random based on occurrence probabilities.

How can I get R to instead select labels 1:3 for subarray 1 and 4:5 for subarray 2, say,  without using subsetting (i.e., []). That is, I want a random subset of labels to be selected for each subarray, instead of all labels assigned to each subarray manually using [].

I know sample() should help.

Using subsetting (which I don't want) one would do

```
x <- 1:5

sample(x[1:3], size, prob = probs[1:3])
```

but this assigns labels 1:3 to ALL subarrays.

Would

```
sample(sample(x), size, replace = TRUE, prob = probs)
```

work?

Any ideas? Please let me know if this is unclear.

Here is a small example, which selects labels from 1:5 for each of 10 subarrays.

```
set.seed(1)

N <- 10
K <- 2
Hstar <- 5
probs <- rep(1/Hstar, Hstar)
perms <- 5

## Set up container(s) to hold the identity of each individual from each permutation ##

num.specs <- ceiling(N / K)

## Create an ID for each haplotype ##

haps <- 1:Hstar

## Assign individuals (N) to each subpopulation (K) ##

specs <- 1:num.specs

## Generate permutations, assume each permutation has N individuals, and sample those individuals' haplotypes from the probabilities ##

gen.perms <- function() {
    sample(haps, size = num.specs, replace = TRUE, prob = probs) # I would like each subarray to contain a random subset of 1:5.
}

pop <- array(dim = c(perms, num.specs, K))

for (i in 1:K) {
    pop[,, i] <- replicate(perms, gen.perms())
}
pop
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Sample works only on one object at a time. If you want a tad more advanced sampling, you'll have to construct a function. What is the reason for not wanting to use subsetting? If subsetting was game, you could do `sample(c(x[1:3], y[4:5]), ...)`.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the arrays and the expected output?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I have multiple subarrays ranging from 2 to 100, so subsetting this way would be quite inefficient.

Comment: @missuse I have posted an example

Comment: Could you ensure it's a reproducible example?

Comment: @CPak I have posted an updated example.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you actually want is something like that

```
num.specs <- 3
haps[sample(seq(haps),size = num.specs,replace = F)]
[1] 3 5 4
```

That is a random subset of your vector haps ?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you want (returns list of matrices instead of 3D array) but this might help

```
lapply(split(1:5, cut(1:5, breaks=c(0, 2, 5))), function(i) matrix(sample(i, 25, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
```

Use `cut` and `split` to partition your vector of character labels before sampling them. Here I split your character labels at the value 2. Also, rather than sampling 5 numbers 5 times, you can sample 25 numbers once, and convert to matrix.

Comment: Almost what I need. But I would like to split at an arbitrary number (so I user don't have to specify it each time). Is there a cleaner way to do this with the array type?

Comment: How can I split it into more that 2 subarrays? I don't see any argument indicating this.

Comment: You can specify breaks as `breaks=c(0, 2, 4, 5)` for instance. Give it a try.